# "Not an answer" flag declined on answer that merely "clarifies" another answer

Tags: discussion, flagging

So I recently flagged this answer: https://superuser.com/a/662949/236545

> Just to clarify, jumbo frames don't need to be enabled on ALL nodes in your network for them to work, only on the sending, receiving, and intermediate nodes. In other words, every node on the path from the sender to the receiver must have jumbo frames enabled. So if you have a router, a NAS, and wired clients A and B, and you want jumbo frames between your NAS and your client A, only the client A, router, and NAS would need to have jumbo frames enabled. Client B will not be able to benefit from jumbo frames, but it can still function on the network, and will not impede other, jumbo frame capable computers from utilizing jumbo frames.

The decline reason was

> "declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer"

But this isn't an answer. It's clarifying another answer, fails to address OP's question, and needs to be posted as a comment instead. That's why I flagged it as not an answer and that's why I posted a comment stating this. Why was this flag declined?

Comment: if it's a clarifying answer, better bet would be to use the custom flag and mention why it should be removed than a generic not an answer. There's no context when looking at the flagging queue and it isn't entirely feasible to look at the entire context for every post that gets flagged

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I handled that flag. On closer inspection, you're right, it's not an answer.

Comment: Is there any way I can have the declined flag reversed or removed from my flags list then?

Comment: @DanteTheEgregore: No, we all have a few declined flags due to moderator error :P

Comment: @DanteTheEgregore it happens, and if you're a regular flagger (or even casual) the occasional mis-handled flag won't affect your score that much.